# Different types of currency in PayPal payouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment

I am studying using PayPal payouts in my ruby On rails application, I would like to know if different types of currencies can be sent in the same batch, as long as they are defined within the items. 
For example:

```
@payout = Payout.new(
  {
    :sender_batch_header => {
      :sender_batch_id => SecureRandom.hex(8),
      :email_subject => 'You have a Payout!',
    },
    :items => [
      {
        :recipient_type => 'EMAIL',
        :amount => {
          :value => '1.0',
          :currency => 'USD'
        },
        :note => 'Thanks for your patronage!',
        :receiver => 'example@mail.com',
        :sender_item_id => "id1",
      },
            {
        :recipient_type => 'EMAIL',
        :amount => {
          :value => '1.0',
          :currency => 'EUR'
        },
        :note => 'Thanks for your patronage!',
        :receiver => 'example2@mail.com',
        :sender_item_id => "id2",
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

Comment: Have you checked the relevant docs for the PayPal api?

Comment: I have not used the PayPal Payouts, but it seems to be possible if you browse through their API documentation at: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/#definition-payout_currency_conversion

Comment: The problem is that nothing is said about my doubt in the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/#definition-payout_item_detail).